# Proving equation is true

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a question

Show that if $x>0$,$y>0$ than:

> $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\geq\frac{4}{{x+y}}$$

How would you solve/start this?

Comment: Please tell us what your thought process is and what you have tried.

Comment: So I would multiply the inequality by $xy(x+y)$, which is positive, as a start.

Comment: I mean this is actually just a manipulation of the $AM\geq HM$ statement...

Comment: What is the end goal here?

Comment: @gen-z-ready-to-perish to prove the equation is true

Comment: @Alex How can we do that if we don’t know what $x$ and $y$ are?

Comment: As far as i know you shouldn’t need to know what x and y are

Comment: I take it you are on a frenzy posting your homework questions for us to do here? @Alex

Comment: Not really it mainly stuff I just don’t understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y>0$. Either $x=y$, $x<y$, or $y<x$. In any case, we have

$$(x-y)^2 \ge 0$$

$$\Rightarrow x^2 - 2xy + y^2 \ge 0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2 + 2xy -4xy + y^2 \ge 0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \ge 4xy$$
$$\Rightarrow (x + y)^2 \ge 4xy$$
$$\Rightarrow (x + y)(x + y) \ge 4xy$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x + y}{xy} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x}{xy} + \frac{y}{xy} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{x} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \geq 2$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$1/x+1/y\geq4/{x+y}\iff (x+y)(1/x+1/y)\geq4$$

$$2+x/y+y/x\geq4 \iff x/y+y/x\ge2$$

to prove that we can use [**Rearrangement inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) that is

$$\frac x y + \frac y x \ge x\frac 1x+y\frac 1y=1$$

Comment: Who’s upvoting a wrong answer? BTW, the OP didn’t want a solution but just a hint instead.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I haven't shown why $x/y+y/x\ge2$.I see instead that solutions are given in the comments.

Comment: The first version of your answer finally concluded that "$x/y>1$", and that answer was upvoted.  Just wondering why ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Indeed I also noticed that and that's no good!For that reason it take a while to mo to recognize the error! Thanks to have pointed that out.

Answer (score -2):

*Hint* One way is simply to show that $$\frac1x+\frac1y-\frac{4}{x+y}\ge 0.$$

Then the rest is just simple algebra.